# Classify values in attribute table that is joined to a raster in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, reclassify

I have a an attribute table that does not have a raster value and is joined to another table that does. How do I reclassify the values in the attribute table?

For example, in column B, I'd like all values <5 to reflect the value 1. How do I do this classification?

Comment: Can't you create a new column and use field calculator for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a shapefile attribute table, you can export the shapefile with its joined table to a new shapefile, and the joined table will become permanent inside the new shapefile's attribute table. Next, add a new field of type integer and use the `Field Calculator`. Then you can write the following python code following [Calculate Field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000), as follows:

```
Parser:
Python

Expression:
Reclass(!Column_B!)

Code Block:
def Reclass(Column):
  if Column < 5:
    return 1
  else
    return 2
```